# How can I run PlayStation 1 CDs on my PC?

Tags: windows-7, emulation, ps1

I have an old PlayStation 1, and I am a big fan of old games. I have a lot of game CDs for this PlayStation.

Is it possible to run these games on my PC? If so, how?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can run them in an emulator such as [ePSXe](http://www.epsxe.com/). Typically emulators require rather powerful machines to run at the kind of FPS you'd expect from the console, however you're unlikely to experience issues with a Playstation emulator and a half-decent PC.

For more information on Playstation emulation, plus a list of emulators, check out the [Emulation General Wiki](http://emulation-general.wikia.com/wiki/PlayStation_emulators).

Just keep in mind that, in most cases, downloading the games themselves is illegal.

Comment: As is obtaining a copy of the PS1 BIOS over the internet IIRC

Comment: @Robotnik: It is as the OS is proprietary.

Answer (score 2):

take one of the emulators from this [list](http://www.emulator-zone.com/doc.php/psx/), install it and play away.  You might want to invest in a gamepad as it will feel a lot more like playing on the actual ps1.  If you have a xbox controller, it should be plug and play with the first one on the list, if i remember correctly.

Answer (score -3):

I personaly use epsxe with hyperspin as a frontend runs most games but some of those which dont run just need a tweek on how they load to work such as some Tomb raider titles with other titles you need the correct Controller plug in to work such as is the case with danger girls and finaly the correct graphics plug in otherwise some graphics may be missing such as invisible characters in dinocrisis 2 just use the right graphics plungin and your good to go same for danger girls use the right controller plug in other wise youo cant play at all one last thing Ive yet to figure out is how to get the game controller to vibrate since theplugin is just not working for reasons ive yet to figure out.